# if a cell has specific formatting, change another cell to a specific value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting

if a cell has specific formatting or text, i need it to then tell another cell to be a specific value. see example picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qMZb.png)

notice how because the cell is green and has white bold text, the cell right above it has a value of 2 and the red cell does not have a value.

The same can apply if a cell is red with yellow bold text. if this is the case, it can subtract 1 point. if cell is yellow text and green background, no points are awarded or taken away. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkEu0.png)

does anyone know how to accomplish this without having to manually do this every time?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Worksheet_Change can be used if the value of the cell actually changes but this doesn't help with colors or formatting.  You can do the same thing with Worksheet_SelectionChange but then you need to click a different cell to make the code execute.  But I don't think there is no way to trigger code when colors change - unless the colors change because the value of a cell changes.

Comment: I think the best way to achieve this is simply via conditional formatting and building those rules in multiple places.  If the users are updating the color of the cell though, you're screwed.  You gotta use the events in VBA as stated from @JerryJeremiah but that has its pitfalls too.

Comment: This question, as it stands, leads to more questions than answers. In order for others to help, I suggest you need to better explain the operating environment (i.e. what leads to what). Separately (at least on the surface of it), it's likely vba might be is the only way to achieve this. However, you haven't said if that's an option, nor (if it is) what you've tried so far.

Answer (score -1):

Color is not data. You can't change a cell value based on another cell's color. Not with a formula and not with VBA. This approach is the wrong way around.

It is quite easy to change a cell's color based on the value of another cell. That can even be done without any formulas or VBA code, using simple conditional formatting.

If you or your users are in the habit of applying color and that color has a specific meaning, well, the best advice here is to change that habit. Excel works on values. Color is not data. It's metadata, and not suitable to serve as the primary tool for data classification.

Comment: Maybe it's just a language thing, but you can of course set cell values (or do any myriad of things) based on cell colors using vba. That said, I agree (philosophically speaking) colors shouldn't be used as a data control tool in excel. But that doesn't mean they can't.

Comment: @Spinner Just because it can be done doesn't mean it's fine to do it. Using color as data is possible but has a long tail of problems and complications, because it's not fit for the job. Yes, theoretically you can do it with VBA, but in order to test for a specific color, you need to ensure that only the colors you are testing for are being used. With the millions of colors available in Excel I challenge you to build me a VBA routine that does something based on the color I selected from the custom color picker. Can you do that?

Comment: I agree with most of your reasoning and I also think the best solution here won't be using cell colors as a switch. But, we don't know we what we don't know. There may be very good reasons the OP must rely on colors (e.g. no control over data source and colors are used as flags). Or maybe, they simply want to. Regardless of any of that though, saying something can't be done when it can, is simply stating a falsehood. As for 'I challenge you to...': I don't see any of that in OP's requirements. The OP only talks about red and green. And yes, I'm pretty sure I can do that. Couldn't you?

Comment: @Spinner Depends on the shade of green, doesn't it? If it's only one shade and its RGB is known (or using the standard limited color picker), then yes. But if the shade of green has been picked from the custom dialog with the whole gamut, no, I couldn't code that. Could you?

Comment: This is getting silly. Several of us have said 'more info required' and 'there's probably a better way'. But let's for a minute take the OP spec on face value and assume the parameters are known (as the OP suggests they are). And let's avoid inventing problems to add to the spec so as to support the view it's impossible. Let's face it... nothing new would ever get done if everyone approached things that way around.